# Determining the location of distutils data files programmatically in Python

Tags: python, packaging, setuptools, distutils, python-module

I'm trying to include data files in distutils for my package and then refer to them using relative paths (following http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#distutils-additional-files)

My dir structure is:

```
myproject/
  mycode.py
  data/
    file1.dat
```

the code in `mycode.py`, which is actually a script in the package.  It relies on accessing `data/file1.dat`, refer to it using that relative path. In `setup.py`, I have:

```
setup(
 ...
 scripts = "myproject/mycode.py"
 data_files = [('data', 'myproject/data/file1.dat')]
)
```

suppose the user now uses:

```
python setup.py --prefix=/home/user/
```

Then `mycode.py` will appear in some place like `/home/user/bin/`.  But the reference to `data/file1.dat` is now broken, since the script lives elsewhere from the data.

How can I find out, from `mycode.py`, the absolute path to `myproject/data/file1.dat`, so I can refer to it properly depending on where the user installed the package?

**EDIT**
When I install this with `prefix=/home/user/`, I get `data/file1.dat` created in `/home/user/` which is exactly what I want, the only missing piece is how to retrieve the absolute path to this file programmatically, given only a relative path and not knowing where the user installed the package. When I try to use `package_data` instead of `data_files`, it does not work - I simply don't get `data/file1.dat` created anywhere, even if I delete my `MANIFEST` file.

I've read all the of the current discussions of this apparently very common problem. All the proposed solutions however are not dealing with the case I have a above, **where the code that needs to access `data_files` is a script** and its location might change depending on the `--prefix` argument to `setup.py`.  The only hack I can think of to resolve this is to add the data file to `scripts=` in `setup()`, as in:

```
setup(
  ...
  scripts = ["myproject/mycode.py", "myproject/data/file1.data"]
)
```

this is a horrible hack but it is the only way I can think of to ensure that `file1.data` will be in the same place as the scripts defined in `scripts=`, since I cannot find any platform independent and installation sensitive API to recover the location of `data_files` after the user ran `setup.py install` (potentially with `--prefix=` args).

Comment: Try mycode.__file__ magic variable inserted into every module?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: __ file __ will not give you the location of the installed module, it can give you the location of the file that is being executed (so if you setup.py install something in ~/lib/site-packages/yourproject/ you will not necessarily get that path back)

Comment: Thats not true. module.__file__ gives you the location of the module where it is being loaded from and that's the place where it is installed?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: you're right I retract my statement

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa How does finding out location of `mycode` module help to answer the question asked which is to find out location of data file?

Comment: Have you solved this problem and if so then how?

Answer (score 14):

I think the confusion arises from the usage of scripts. Scripts should refer to a runnable executable, perhaps a utility script related to your package or perhaps an entry point into functionality for your package. In either case, you should expect that any scripts will not be installed alongside the rest of your package. This expectation is due mainly to the convention that packages are considered libraries (and installed to lib directories) whereas scripts are considered executables (and installed to bin or Scripts directories). Furthermore, data files are neither executables nor libraries and are completely separate.

So from the script, you need to determine where the data files are located. According to the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files),

> If directory is a relative path, it is interpreted relative to the
>   installation prefix.

Therefore, you should write something like the following in the mycode script to locate the data file:

```
import sys
import os

def my_func():
    with open(os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'data', 'file1.dat')) as f:
        print(next(f))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_func()
```

If you're not pleased with the way that your code and data are not bundled together (and I would not be), then I would restructure your package so that you have an actual Python package (and module) and use packages= and package_data= to inject the data into the package, and then create a simple script that calls into the module in the package.

I did that by creating this tree:

```
.
│   setup.py
│
├───myproject
│   │   mycode.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───data
│           file1.dat
│
└───scripts
        run-my-code.py
```

With setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='myproject',
    version='1.0',
    scripts=['scripts/run-my-code.py'],
    packages=['myproject'],
    package_data = {
        'myproject': ['data/file1.dat'],
    },
)
```

run-my-code.py is simply:

```
from myproject import mycode

mycode.my_func()
```

`__init__` is empty and mycode.py looks like:

```
import os

here = os.path.dirname(__file__)

def my_func():
    with open(os.path.join(here, 'data', 'file1.dat')) as f:
        print(next(f))
```

This latter approach keeps the data and code bundled together (in site-packages/myproject) and only installs the script in a different location (so it shows up in the $PATH).

Comment: I would change `os.path.join(here, 'data/file1.dat')` to `os.path.join(here, 'data', 'file1.dat')`, but that's almost just a matter of style, since os.path manages slashes _automagically_.

Comment: You can overwrite the location of data files via `--install-data=<path>` which will simply break this approach. As such, I don't think you are supposed to rely on sys.prefix at all.

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to use [pkg_resources.resource_filename](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#iresourceprovider) to get the filename of a file in your package_data.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go. It's like tired Indiana Jones meets a guy to fight with, and as he has a gun at hand, he simply shoots him.

Comment: This does not work with file installed via `data_files`. It works with files installed via `package_data`.

Answer (score 0):

For a solution that'll work nicely inside/outside a `virtualenv` on Windows/Linux import `pip` and `os` then run:

```
os.path.split(os.path.split(pip.__file__)[0])[0]
```

#### Full example

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from os import path
from functools import partial
from pip import __file__ as pip_loc


if __name__ == '__main__':
    package_name = 'gen'

    templates_join = partial(path.join, path.dirname(__file__),
                             package_name, 'templates')
    install_to = path.join(path.split(path.split(pip_loc)[0])[0],
                           package_name, 'templates')

    setup(
        name=package_name,
        version='0.0.1',
        test_suite=package_name + '.tests',
        packages=find_packages(),
        package_dir={package_name: package_name},
        data_files=[(install_to, [templates_join('.gitignore'),
                                  templates_join('logging.conf')])]
    )
```

Reference (my own): https://stackoverflow.com/a/29120636