# Including .gitignore in setup? - Error: doesn't exist or not a regular file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, setuptools, distutils

#### setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from os import path
from functools import partial


if __name__ == '__main__':
    package_name = 'gen'
    templates_join = partial(path.join, path.dirname(__file__), package_name,
                             'templates')
    setup(
        name=package_name,
        test_suite=package_name + '.tests',
        packages=find_packages(),
        package_dir={package_name: package_name},
        package_data={package_name: [templates_join('.gitignore')]}
    )
```

#### Tree

```
.
├── gen
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── .gitignore
└── setup.py
```

#### Error

> error: can't copy 'gen/ld/gen/templates/.gitignore': doesn't exist or not a regular file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed that using [`data_files`](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files) works inside/outside a `virtualenv` on Linux and Windows:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from os import path
from functools import partial
from pip import __file__ as pip_loc


if __name__ == '__main__':
    package_name = 'gen'

    templates_join = partial(path.join, path.dirname(__file__),
                             package_name, 'templates')
    install_to = path.join(path.split(path.split(pip_loc)[0])[0],
                           package_name, 'templates')

    setup(
        name=package_name,
        version='0.0.1',
        test_suite=package_name + '.tests',
        packages=find_packages(),
        package_dir={package_name: package_name},
        data_files=[(install_to, [templates_join('.gitignore'),
                                  templates_join('logging.conf')])]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use `abspath(split(__file__)[0])` instead.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from functools import partial
from os.path import join, abspath, split

if __name__ == '__main__':
    package_name = 'gen'
    templates_join = partial(join, abspath(split(__file__)[0]), 'gen', 'templates')

    setup(
        name=package_name,
        test_suite=package_name + '.tests',
        packages=find_packages(),
        package_dir={package_name: package_name},
        package_data={package_name: [templates_join('.gitignore')]}
    )
```

Let me know if it's work.

Comment: Unfortunately that failed. Would prefer to use stdlib rather than `os2emxpath`; which is what I tested with.

Comment: Yeah, however I've tried that and it didn't work for me. Did it work for you?

Comment: Yeah, it works for me. Oh sorry, package 'gen' should be added. Use the new answer and try again.

Comment: No, that also failed.